# Is it possible to put a path varaible inside the controllers request mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a standard BREAD controller where all operations URLs are as follow

| Operation | Method | function | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Browse* | GET | *index* | `/api/levels/{levelId}/items` |
| *Read* | GET | *show* | `/api/levels/{levelId}/items/{id}` |
| *Edit* | PUT | *update* | `/api/levels/{levelId}/items/{id}` |
| *Add* | POST | *create* | `/api/levels/{levelId}/items` |
| *Delete* | DELETE | *delete* | `/api/levels/{levelId}/items/{id}` |

I have my `ItemController`

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/levels")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemController {
/*...*/
    @PutMapping("/{levelId}/items/{id}")
    public void update(@Valid @RequestBody ItemRequest request, @PathVariable Long levelId, @PathVariable Long id) {
        service.update(request, id, levelId);
    }
/*...*/
}
```

Is it possible to set the `levelId` path varaible inside the controller request mapping like this

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/levels/{levelId}/items")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemController {
/*...*/
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public void update(@Valid @RequestBody ItemRequest request, @PathVariable Long levelId, @PathVariable Long id) {
        service.update(request, id, levelId);
    }
/*...*/
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried instead of asking?

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't run it. It's a delicate situation, I can't just guess that I'm right and execute it hoping it works. I can't afford losing or modifying the data even though this is still in dev environment

Comment: That is what unit tests are for. Writing 1 simple test would have answered your question.

Comment: Short answer: You can do it. The path variable can be placed either in RequestMapping or in the method mapping or in both. Just follow the naming in your parameter names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping("/api/levels/{levelId}/items")
```

Yes, it is possible, and this should work.

If you are seeing an error while running this, edit your post and add it.